# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in Python

Tags: python

I get this error and I don't know what the problem is.

Code:

```
__author__ = 'victor'

import requests
import xmltodict
url = 'http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-storingen?station=UT'
user = 'victor_shao@hotmail.com'
passw = 'dMHAg67WACsUdrQmqctr3giaTpTnsJmhPP2EcQWlVnMw3zmHXvSE-A'
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, passw))

xmldi = xmltodict.parse(response.text)

storing = 0
allestoringen = 4

print("Storingen",'\n','ongeplande storingen')
print('{0:15s}'.format('id'),'{0:40s}'.format('traject'),'{0:20s}'.format('reden'),'{0:100s}'.format('bericht'),'{0:25s}'.format('datum'))
for storing in range(0, allestoringen):
    id = xmldi['Storingen']['Ongepland']['Storing']['id']
    traject = xmldi['Storingen']['Ongepland']['Storing']['Traject']
    reden = xmldi['Storingen']['Ongepland']['Storing']['Reden']
    bericht = xmldi['Storingen']['Ongepland']['Storing']['Bericht']
    datum = xmldi['Storingen']['Ongepland']["Storing"]['Datum']

print("Geplande storingen ")
print('{0:25s)'.format('id'),'{0:40s}'.format('traject'),'{0:35s}'.format('periode'),'{0:200s}'.format('advies'),'{0:250s}'.format('bericht'),'{0:50s}'.format('oorzaak'),'{0:30s}'.format('vertraging'))
for storing in range(0, allestoringen):
    id = xmldi['Storingen']['Gepland']['Storing']['id']
    traject = xmldi['Storingen']['Gepland']['Storing']['Traject']
    periode = xmldi['Storingen']['Gepland']['Storing']['Periode']
    advies = xmldi['Storingen']['Gepland']['Storing']['Advies']
    bericht = xmldi['Storingen']['Gepland']['Storing']['Bericht']
    oorzaak = xmldi['Storingen']['Gepland']['Storing']['Oorzaak']
    vertraging = xmldi['Storingen']['Gepland']['Storing']['Vertraging']
```

Here is the output, where I should fill in the information:

> C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/avi/PycharmProjects/untitled1/storing.py Storingen
> ongeplande storingen id              traject
> reden                bericht
> datum                     Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/avi/PycharmProjects/untitled1/storing.py", line 18, in
>
> id = xmldi['Storingen']['Ongepland']['Storing']['id'] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

How can I fix this? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Looks like `xmltodict.parse(response.text)` (or possibly one of its nested dictionaries) returned `None`.

Comment: More precisely, `xmldi['Storingen']['Ongepland']` is `None` on line 18.

Comment: what does that mean None and how can i solve this error?

Comment: Which book, Web site, or teacher are you using that doesn't explain what None is? We need to know so that we don't recommend that resource to anyone else.

Comment: `Ongepland` has no data. Also, I can log in as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `xmldi['Storingen']['Ongepland']` has the value `None`

```py
id = xmldi['Storingen']['Ongepland']['Storing']['id']
```

should be changed to:

```py
id = xmldi['Storingen']['Gepland']['Storing']['id']
```